# redis-cluster,migrating importing state issue

Tags: redis-cluster

I Create a redis cluster:

```
M: dbaf0a596c4f5a2f4ac1d9de2ed5c117f201d26d localhost:9501
slots:5461-10922 (5462 slots) master
2 additional replica(s)

S: a375ec8221f9872f8f287bca8a67fcef701cef72 localhost:9000
slots: (0 slots) slave
replicates dbaf0a596c4f5a2f4ac1d9de2ed5c117f201d26d

S: a319a75ac0ee58484e345d7996a6712335ebddf5 localhost:9001
slots: (0 slots) slave
replicates dbaf0a596c4f5a2f4ac1d9de2ed5c117f201d26d

M: 05f7d7cc87b417ad4bdf61b3877a674d54c02ef7 localhost:9002
slots:10923-16383 (5461 slots) master
1 additional replica(s)

S: 932dfde44c77d341b873bf205c3d069b236c424a localhost:9502
slots: (0 slots) slave
replicates 05f7d7cc87b417ad4bdf61b3877a674d54c02ef7

M: 69ec05cbf01c81474ea1ccf8848d3f336c99200b localhost:9500
slots:0-5460 (5461 slots) master
0 additional replica(s)
```

//cluster keyslot b (in slot 3300)

//cluster keyslot g581 (in slot 3300)

redis-cli -h localhost -p 9500 -c

```
1. localhost:9500> set b 1 //b store in 9500 node
2. localhost:9500> cluter setslot 3300 migrating 9002_NODE_ID
3. localhost:9500> set g581 2 //(error) ASK 3300 localhost:9002
```

redis-cli -h localhost -p 9002 -c

1. localhost:9002> set g581 2 //Redirected to slot [3300] located at localhost:9500`

now Can I write data into slot 3300

Comment: Improved Formatting  and remove unnecessary word .

Answer (score 1):

When you want to transfer redis slot in a cluster, steps below are requried:

1. use two "`cluster setslot`" commands to set source node migrating and destination node importing

   CLUSTER SETSLOT  IMPORTING

   CLUSTER SETSLOT  MIGRATING
2. use `CLUSTER GETKEYSINSLOT` to get all keys in this slot, and for each slot, use `MIGRATE` to transfer data.
3. use `CLUSTER SETSLOT <slot> NODE <node_id>` to transfer the slot to new node officially.

So it's not a good option to handle redis slot yourself, better use redis-trib to do the managing.